# bundle SCSS and JS separately in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, bundle

I use a webpack config for bundling my JS and SCSS files in src directory and this worked fine but I want **multiple output**. *(not one file like bundle.js)* One for js, one for css.

My ideal output in **public folder**:

- styles/**main.css**
- scripts/**main.js**

this is my config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/scripts'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    publicPath: '/scripts/',
  },
};
```

I also used the `ExtractTextPlugin` and `MiniCssExtractPlugin` but I didn't get the result.

Comment: You need to use the `MiniCssExtractPlugin`
here [examplo setting](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#string)
maybe you were missing the `public_path`

Comment: @LuisSilva thanks. I try this but not worked for me. can you give a real example based on my config?

Comment: I encourage you to try, but here a [example](https://github.com/lesm/lesm.github.io/blob/source/webpack.config.js)